# PDF Encryption Using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code below takes in a single pdf file and then encrypts it, What i want it to do is to take a directory containing pdf files and encrypt the files in that directory automatically, instead of specifying each file explicitly. Please help !

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input_pdf', required=True,
                        help='Input pdf file')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--user_password', required=True,
                        help='output CSV file')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--owner_password', default=None,
                        help='Owner Password')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    set_password(args.input_pdf, args.user_password, args.owner_password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't intended to be a code-writing service, but we're happy to help if you run into a problem that hasn't been asked here before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir('/some/directory/that/has/pdfs')
for file in glob.glob('*.pdf'):
    set_password(file, upass, opass)
```

Comment: Thanks you bunches, that worked perfectly. I also got to know about a new library glob today and a new way to achieve things. I am sure this will come handy in my future scripts.